# increasing the Width for a TD that comes after a TD with specific text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have the following markup :-
[image]

now i want using CSS selector to maximize the width for a  from 850 to 900. but i want to specify the the TD which i want to expand should match the following:-

- Be inside a Table with class = ms-formtable
- and inside a TR
- be after a TD with the word "Description" inside the `<nobr>` tag.

Can anyone adivce on this please?

Comment: css selectors probably won't help. they're for what amounts to a linear path "through" the branches of the tree. it's not easy to query parallel/sibling nodes.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the reply so what is the approach i need to follow then ? to use jquery selectors ?

Comment: If you can get the contents of your `td` into a `data` attribute (say `data-td-contents="description"` then you can use `td[data-td-contents="description"] + td` as a selector. But that is so specific that even changing a capital letter will make the rule invalid. Not really recommended, but possible.

Comment: this is a third party application and i can not modify the markup itself to ass a data-attribute. i can only write custom css and scripts against the built-in markup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the contents of your `td` into a `data attribute` like this:

```
<td data-td-content="Description">Description</td>
```

then you can use

```
td[data-td-contents="description"] + td
```

as a CSS selector. But that is so specific that even changing a capital letter will make the rule invalid. Not really recommended, but possible. It also doubles up the amount of data you'd be passing and processing, doubling the size of your page. Not ideal.

You could also use jQuery for this, using the `:contains()` selector. You can do the following:

```
$("td:contains('Description') + td")
```

This will return the elements that follow after the `td` that contains the text value, which you then can work with. Heres an example in a snippet that shows it works:

```js
$("td:contains('description') + td").addClass('selected')
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>My Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>description</td>
    <td>My Description</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

This, of course, requires you to have access to the script as well. Otherwise there is no direct way to select such a thing.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: thanks for the great help.. but to avoid affecting unrelated TD. how i can specify that the TD i am checking its ":contain(Descriptions)" should be inside a table with a class= .ms-formtable, other wise the TD should not be selected.. ?

Comment: Just add it to the selector before this. So: `.ms-formtable td:contains('Description') + td`